# Can't pass data from main.js to App.vue in Vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my main.js I do authentication and after that I populate a data property.  I'm trying to pass that data property to the App component but seems not possible?

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

new Vue({
  data: {
    test: 'test'
  },
  //render: h => h(App)
  render: h => h(App, { props: { 'test': this.test }})
}).$mount('#app')
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app" :test="test">
    <h1>{{test}}</h1>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  props: ['test']
}
</script>
```

Just gives error as test and/or this.test is undefined.  Passing a hard-coded value works.  Without using props on the render line has no errors but App doesn't receive data.  Am I just doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `render` to a normal function in order for `this` to refer to the `Vue` instance:

```
render: function (h) {
  return h(App, { props: { test: this.test } });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're defining `render` as an anonymous arrow function. which means that it's `this` context isn't bind to you Vue instance. if you want a function's context to be the "hosting" object, you must define it with the `function` syntax.

```
new Vue({
  data: {
    test: 'test'
  },
  render(h) {
    return h(App, { props: { 'test': this.test }})
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

you can read about arrow function vs regular functions [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/difference-between-regular-functions-and-arrow-functions-f65639aba256)